# What is the difference between the two weston-simple examples?

Tags: wayland

what difference between weston-simple-egl and weston-simple-shm?

1) weston-simple-egl

[image: weston-simple-egl]

2) weston-simple-shm

[image: weston-simple-shm]

Answer (score 0):

They differ in type of buffer being used

i.e
for simple-shm you use wl_shm interface to create buffer from shared memory pool(wl_shm_pool_create_buffer) write pixels and render.

for simple-egl you use egl api to create buffer and render.